# How to open 'Print Preview' popup of a browser using shortcut key 'meta+P' in Cypress

Tags: cypress, keyboard-events, cypress-real-events

I want to open the 'Print Preview' popup a browser which is launched by Cypress. Here is what I did:

```js
it('test', () => {
  cy.visit("https://www.google.com/");
  cy.wait(5000)

  //Attempt 1
  cy.document().trigger('keydown', { metaKey: true, key: "p", code: "p", which: 80 })

  //Attempt 2
  cy.document().trigger('keydown', { metaKey: true, key: "p", code: "keyP", which: 80 })

  //Attempt 3
  cy.document().trigger('keydown', { metaKey: true, keyCode: 80, which: 80 })

  //Attempt 4
  cy.document().trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 80, metaKey: true });

  //Attempt 5
  cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { metaKey: true, key: "p", code: "p", which: 80 })

  //Attempt 6
  cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { metaKey: true, key: "p", code: "keyP", which: 80 })
        
  //Attempt 7
  cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { metaKey: true, keyCode: 80, which: 80 })
        
  //Attempt 8
  cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 80, metaKey: true });

})
```

I also tried methods from 'cypress-real-event' (https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) but with no luck.

Comment: Are you trying to test the print preview will show up for the keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Yes, as part of a scenario, I need to launch the print preview popup.
Also, in my other project, I need to open an installed plugin using its shortcut and that will also be solved by this same approach.

Comment: Checking browser shortcut for print previews sounds like out of scope for your app testing.

Comment: Consider this - I have an external plugin installed in browser. To launch this plugin, I have shortcut "option(alt)+k". Now I want to use this shortcut to execute the plugin in Cypress.